# jQuery is not making asynchronous call evel async:false specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code

```
var jsonpath;

function loginFromDef() {

    var a = grantAccess($('#login :input').serialize());
    if (a.Msg) {
        $('#msg').html(a.Msg).attr('class', 'error');
    }
    else if (a.done) {
        var returnUrl = getQueryString('ReturnURL');
        if (returnUrl)
            window.location = returnUrl;
        else
            window.location = 'Home.aspx';
    }


    return false;
}

function grantAccess(dataToPost) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jsonpath + 'Json.ashx?method=GrantAccess',
        async: false,
        data: dataToPost,
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
}

function getQueryString(name) {
    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
```

`var jsonPath` is being defined in Default.aspx page where from I m calling function `loginFromDef()` on `onclick` event of submit button.

I am getting error **`TypeError: a is undefined`**
Don't worry about my `.ashx` handler. It is working fine. I'd test it.

I think `var a` in function `loginFromDef` is not being initialized. Because **`may be jQuery is making asynchronous call. Even I have set async:false`** in options.

Whats wrong with me..?? Please suggest a solution to this.

Comment: You don't have any return statement in `grantAccess`. The return statement inside the callback does not have any effect (since it is called by `$.ajax` internally). The Ajax call *is* asynchronous but you are not returning any data from `grantAccess`.

Comment: @felix that looks like it should be an answer :) (p.s. I think you mean *synchronous*)

Comment: @nbrooks: Yes and yes :)

Comment: Just because you want to return something from a `grantAccess` function you shouldn't use synchronous Ajax requests. Redesign your functionality to use async ones instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have any return statement in `grantAccess`. The return statement inside the callback does not have any effect (since it is called by `$.ajax` internally).

The Ajax call *is* synchronous but you are not returning any data from `grantAccess`.

You could do:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: jsonpath + 'Json.ashx?method=GrantAccess',
    async: false,
    data: dataToPost,
}).responseText;
```

*Maybe you have to use `$.parseJSON` before you return that value.*

`$.ajax` returns a `jqXHR` object, which you can find more information for in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

However, I **strongly** suggest to not use synchronous Ajax calls and I don't see any reason why you would need one here. Synchronous request can potentially block the browser (including its UI) until the response was received, making the browser unresponsive which leads to a bad use experience.

Change your code so that you can use callbacks to handle the response. For example:

```
function loginFromDef() {

    grantAccess($('#login :input').serialize()).done(function(a) {
        if (a.Msg) {
            $('#msg').html(a.Msg).attr('class', 'error');
        }
        else if (a.done) {
            var returnUrl = getQueryString('ReturnURL');
            if (returnUrl)
                window.location = returnUrl;
            else
                window.location = 'Home.aspx';
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

where `grantAccess` simply returns the `jqXHR` object returned by `$.ajax`:

```
function grantAccess(dataToPost) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jsonpath + 'Json.ashx?method=GrantAccess',
        data: dataToPost
    });
}
```

Comment: @Robert: The `jqXHR` object returned by `$.ajax` implements the promise interface. It really is that simple. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR (maybe it was not clear that it is returned, I explicitly stated it now).

Comment: Why you removed `.responseText;` from `grantAccess()`. You have have used it before. In that case what will `grantAccess()` will return.
You have suggest me not to use synchronous. What are the drwabacks of using this in my case..?? Please define some drawbacks in ur answers

Comment: @Shashwat: It will directly return the `jqXHR` object instead of the value of its `responseText` property. Have a look at the documentation regarding that object. The drawback with synchronous request is that they can block the browser (and its UI) until the response was received. And there is nothing worse than an unresponsive UI.

Comment: @Felix: I know about that, but when I was making my comment your code was actually adding a `done` function on the serialized data object which **was incorrect**. Now that you've put parentheses on the right places deferred object can actually work as expected.

Comment: @FelixKling Thnx a lot friend. Your answer is very descriptive. It really helps me. Can u please tell where can I define an error function to call in `loginFromDef(..)` function in case request got `timed out` or `internal server error 500` etc.

Comment: @Shashwat: You can pass another callback to `.fail` (which is the same as defining adding an `error` callback to the `$.ajax` configuration). It would look like `grantAccess(...).done(...).fail(...)`.

Comment: @FelixKling what are the the other callbacks that I can use in different cases. Please tell me. I m new to jQuery. looking on ur projects on GitHub

Comment: @Shashwat: Have a look at the `$.ajax` and `jqXHR` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR. The documentation is really good, it's worth reading it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your `grantAccess` function is returning after the AJAX call is being made. Since you are not specifying a return for the `grantAccess` function, it's implicitly returning `undefined`.

You're `success` function is then returning the `data` variable to it's **caller**, which is somewhere in jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `success` function of your Ajax call.

```
function grantAccess(dataToPost) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jsonpath + 'Json.ashx?method=GrantAccess',
        async: false,
        data: dataToPost,
        success: function (data) {
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

The success function is different from the GrantAccess function. GrantAccess does not return a value, therefore the following line:

```
var a = grantAccess($('#login :input').serialize());
```

will **always** result in `a` being `null`.

What you should do is the following:

```
function loginFromDef() {

    grantAccess($('#login :input').serialize());
}

function grantAccess(dataToPost) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: jsonpath + 'Json.ashx?method=GrantAccess',
        async: false,
        data: dataToPost,
        success: TheFollowUpFunction(data)
    });
}

    //NEWLY ADDED:

    function TheFollowUpFunction(a) {

        if (a.Msg) {
            $('#msg').html(a.Msg).attr('class', 'error');
     }
    else if (a.done) {
         var returnUrl = getQueryString('ReturnURL');
          if (returnUrl)
            window.location = returnUrl;
          else
            window.location = 'Home.aspx';
    }

    }
```

Comment: a will **never** be `null` because **nothing** is being returned.

Comment: null/undefined/... call it what you want. It will be an uninitialized variable.

Comment: `null` is a concrete value though ;)

Comment: An `undefined` object is something that is **not defined**, not defined as `null`

Comment: I work in C# ans JS simultaneously, the definitions tend to spill over at times. You are semantically correct, but it doesn't change the issue at hand :)

Comment: I agree, however `null` signifies that an object, or a return value is like that for a reason, whereas `undefined` could be the product of a mispell, bad indexing or many other forms of bad logic.